# Login again on pressing browser back button even after logout successfully

Tags: grails, spring-security

Whenever i press browser back button,it takes me to application's home page without any data even after successfully logout.This only shows page header part and on pressing any menu option brings me back to login page.
I am using Grails-2.3.6 along with JDK-6.
So any body can suggest me what could be the problem as i am new on grails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a common problem in web development, the page is cached in the browser, so when you press the back button, the browser show what is in his cache. In order to solve this you need to set the expires headers in your pages. In grails the easiest way of do that is using filters:

Create the fie  `grails-app/conf/RequestFilters.groovy` with this content:

```
  class RequestFilters {
     def filters = {
        requestHeadersFilter(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            after = {
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L)
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store")
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

For safari you will need another small hack, add `onunload=""` to the body of your layouts (views/layouts)